# Weird semi-transparent box appears after hover

Tags: html, css

I've noticed this weird bug in CSS and have no idea why it is happening.

Initial state:

[image: initial state of a button]

Hover state:

[image: Hover state of the same button]

After hover:
[image: Box after hover]

I tried debugging, but this box is nowhere to be found. Any ideas?

You can observe this on this page https://busko.si/settings.html (it happens on all similar buttons and switches, sometimes on hover sometimes on click in Chrome and Safari).

And if its any help, here is the CSS for the button:

```
.button-wrapper {
    background: var(--text-color);
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    transition: background 200ms;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.button-inner {
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: var(--text-color-alt);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this when visiting your site.  Which browsers and what versions are you using?

Comment: Hey, I've tested it in Chrome 79 and Safari 13. It unfortunately doesn't happen always. I've also seen it happen on mobile Chrome on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. You need to either remove **overflow: scroll** or use **overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;** . There is something wonky with using scroll.